# Setting up the inoreader API in R

Tags: r, post, httr

I am attempting to access the inoreader API in `R` using the `httr` package. So far I am failing because of my limited understanding of how an API request work. I was wondering if anyone could help me to get started, by creating a function to retrieve the [OAuth 2.0 bearer token](https://www.inoreader.com/developers/oauth).

This is where I got so far:

```
library(httr); library(jsonlite)

token <- function(client_id_f, redirect_uri_f) {
    POST("/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1",
         config=add_headers(
         `Host`="www.inoreader.com",
         `Content-length`="217",
         `Content-type`="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
         `User-agent`="your-user-agent"
       ),
         body = list(client_id=client_id_f,
                     redirect_uri=redirect_uri_f,
                     scope='read',
                     state='guydqwgusadhdashijdsahj')
       )-> res
    
    stop_for_status(res)
    
    content(res)
    }
```

And unsurprisingly the response is `URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (Caveat: I don't use any APIs that use OAuth2.) I know that most things trying to access an API protected by OAuth2 tend to be harder to configure. Not impossible, but certainly more steps involved than with (say) basic-authentication. Have you attempted to use [`httr::oauth2.0_token`](https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/oauth2.0_token.html)?

Comment: Thank you for this. No, I haven't but I will definitely look into that. Personally, I would still like to learn how to configure a request if anyone can throw me a bone!

Comment: It seems like "HTTP/1.1" should not be part of the URL. Try just 'POST("/oauth2/token"', ...)` but even then there should be a domain name in there

Comment: *"how to configure a request"* ... OAuth2 is neither easy nor optional. That function is written to make it less difficult. I believe there is no way around it, you cannot do a single/simple `POST` and hope to work around OAuth2. See https://blog.r-hub.io/2021/01/25/oauth-2.0/ (I just found it, cannot attest to it fully).

Comment: Thank you. Following your suggestion, I have used `oauth2.0_token` and successfully prompt a browser authentication. Is there any way to authenticate in R without passing through the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer I thought it would be worth sharing.

```
#libraries
library(httr2); library(tidyverse)
                    
#set up client           
inoreader_client <- function() {oauth_client(
id = your_id,
token_url = "https://www.inoreader.com/oauth2/token",
secret=obfuscated(your_token),      
name = your_name)}                  

# get stream
stream <- request('https://www.inoreader.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/user%2F')`               %>%
req_oauth_auth_code(
client = inoreader_client(),
scope="read",
auth_url = "https://www.inoreader.com/oauth2/authorize",           
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:1410/') %>% 
req_url_query(n=999) %>%
req_perform() %>%
resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE)
```